# Get a specific row data in CSV using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, csv, row

Given a specific row number, is there a way to get the data of that row in a CSV file, so that I can manipulate that data?

I want it to do in this way such that I can keep track of which rows I have got and manipulated.

Every CSV module actually reads the whole file and parse the data but I just need a reference rather than loading whole file as file gets changed.

How could I do that?

This is my Node.JS code:

```
var csv = require('csv');
var fs = require('fs');
var str = csv().from.stream(fs.createReadStream('test.csv'))
str.transform( function(row){
  row.unshift(row.pop());
  return row;  
})
.on('record', function(row,index){
  console.log('#'+index+' '+JSON.stringify(row));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be what you need: https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-line

Get the first line for the headers of the csv (if there is any), get the line you want, concat both lines separated by `\n` and use your usual csv-parser to parse it and get a nice object back.

Comment: var getLine = require('get-line');
var fs = require('fs');
var rs = fs.createReadStream('test.csv')

 
// get data from line 10000 to 10010 
var getLine = getLine({lines: [100, 1500], newline: '\n'}, cb);
 
function cb(line) {
    console.log(line);
    // return an array of the data in the range 
}
 
 Getting input nothing

Comment: You missed the most important line of the example: `rs.pipe(getLine)`

Comment: After few tests, I saw that this library doens't pass any argument to the callback so you should pipe it to your csv stream: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv#pipe-example